# How to extract values based on keys or subkeys in PyMongo

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a json file called student.json with content as below :

```
    {
      "Student": [
        {
          "fees": "$21.00"
        },
        {
          "date": "19/11/2018"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now I am trying to extract the values for "fees" and "date" using PyMongo for further analysis , but it's not working. Please suggest.

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['student_db']
collection_student = db['student']

with open('student.json') as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)

collection_student.insert_one(file_data)
with client:
    db = client.student_db
    a = db.student.find({"Student.fees": 1})
    print(a.next())
```

on Mongo Console I tried like this :

```
db.student.aggregate([
{
    $unwind : "$Student"
},
{
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        Student : 1
    }
}
])
```

output :

```
{ "Student" : { "fees" : "$21.00" } }
{ "Student" : { "date" : "19/11/2018" } }
```

Edited(1) :
As per suggestion I tried as below but it's printing {} for 'date'. How to avoid this ?

```
db.student.find({},{"Student.fees":1});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df3656fb3439edbccd2cca9"), "Student" : [ { "fees" : "$21.00" }, {  } ] }
```

Edited(2) : Tried and some what it's working on console :

```
db.getCollection('student').find().forEach(function(student){
... ... print("Student _id : " + student._id);
... ... print("Student Key : " + JSON.stringify(student.Student[0]));
... ... print("Student Fees : " + student.Student[0].fees)
... ... print("Student Date : " + student.Student[1].date)
... ... })

Student _id : 5df3656fb3439edbccd2cca9
Student Key : {"fees":"$21.00", "date":"19/11/2018"}
Student Fees  : $21.00
Student Date  : 19/11/2018
```

Comment: db.student.find({},{"Student.fees":1}) try this

Comment: @HarshitVadhera {} will be printed for "date". I want to avoid that. Basically when I want to query fees then it should give the result= $21.00. Thanks for the suggestion